# Is It any way to Optimize my query Using MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm new when it come to Query Optimization and this is my first time stumble in this problem.

When I make a query usually it only for around **5000-10000** data, but I'm quite shock when know that my query can't fetch data around **40000-60000** since in php my admin tell me that the query failed to fetch because it's take too long to get the data using my query, so can someone help me to optimize my query in here? I'm quite confused since I can already cut the time from **who knows seconds** since it failed to fetch until it can fetch with around **14-16 seconds** since i find that `REGEXP` clause have a worse query time than `IN` and `Equal` clause, but I'm still wondering is my query still possible to optimize so It can get below **14 seconds**

this is MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    aList.`UserId`,
    aList.`email`,
    aList.`FullName`,
    aList.`aTime`,
    aList.`NotifToken`
FROM 
    (SELECT
        aPerson.`UserId`,
        aPerson.`email`,
        aProf.`FullName`,
        REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(aPerson.`NotifTokens`, CONCAT('$[', Numbers.N - 1, '].time')), '"', '') AS aTime,
        REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(aPerson.`NotifTokens`, CONCAT('$[', Numbers.N - 1, '].id')), '"', '') AS NotifToken
    FROM
    (
        SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS N FROM 
        (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) T2,
        (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) T1, 
        (SELECT @row:=0) T0
    ) Numbers -- Natural numbers from 1 to 100
    INNER JOIN takoshu_login_v2.`persons` AS aPerson ON Numbers.N <= JSON_LENGTH(aPerson.`NotifTokens`)
    LEFT JOIN takoshu_login_v2.`prof` AS aProf ON aProf.`UserId` = aPerson.`UserId`
    LEFT JOIN takoshu_examreport_v1.`exam_test_participant` AS aTest ON aTest.`UserId` = aPerson.`UserId`
    WHERE aPerson.`EmailConfirmation` = 1 AND (aTest.`EventId` NOT IN ("1", "2","3") OR aTest.`EventId` IS NULL) AND aProf.`Class` IN ("Biology", "Mathematics", "Chemistry") GROUP BY aPerson.`UserId`
    ORDER BY aTime DESC) AS aList
GROUP BY aList.`UserId`
```

Notes:

1. Notif Token field is a Json so I must extract it so I can get the JSON id for the notifToken field
2. If you ask why there is numbers in there, I use it for looping

**EDIT 1**

This is The example of the notif Json that I must to fetch

```
[
  {
    "time": "2019-11-25T10:17:03.609Z",
    "id": "e9KsB96Pnk:APA91bEMOrIkrUDe6KaXXD6f92_bWHlVTvgff8FCCMK9If_4wDLmaFu0FS1y04ywiwZoKgYPADIldZucnDdpyg--BslzCrcnhy0VBEl49tpqZRej0ZCIIeFM0QCxNoWjDgJtP8D6sTtP"
  },
  {
    "time": "2019-12-02T09:55:31.107Z",
    "id": "d_HuGJWFpWw:APA91bE7KKPOZGXFqygMdJO4yXXLRzM_vpFdWvxMG-TQw0cIZ6TNpoPNqMqInOic8wV-Z1TgyaLOLgpxxj0MJMBMUDWXt3PsEd8uOsff2ULahgZQM_IZxcppKNKjA-b-pW6LO2p0u_xD"
  }
]
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for the tables referenced and `EXPLAIN {query}` to see how its executed.

Comment: @Nick I'm Using 5.7.24 for MySQL Version

Comment: Can you provide an SQLfiddle ?

Comment: Is it returning thousands of rows when it does not timeout?

Comment: @RickJames It is not returning anything since there is only red warning in the middle of the screen that said fetch data failed timeout error if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

Do not hide data inside structures.  (In this case JSON.)

It seems like you need a 3-column table with up to 100 rows for the JSON data.  The columns would be `time`, `id`, and `N`.

After you have moved the data from JSON into such a table, rewrite the query.  Then, if you still have performance problems, we can discuss further.